# Laptop goes to sleep on any keyboard key press

Tags: keyboard, suspend

Just installed elementary OS and system goes to sleep on any keyboard key press(system shuts down if a key is pressed at the login screen). Important to mention is that this only happens with the internal keyboard (the USB one works just fine). Laptop Asus vivobook E200HA

Answer (score 1):

Try to update plugging in  external keyboard and mouse. I have solved the problem in this way.